# How to dynamically update forms in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making my first 2D scroller game. I've coded all my movements and obstacle collisions. Eventually I'm going to have a lot of panels and picture boxes on my form that my first level will be really messy if I have more than 30 picture boxes (enemies collisions, etc.).

Every level will be different, so sometimes enemy bosses or collision will vary in sizes. So my question is is there a way I can dynamically update new forms that I can code with differ my obstacles, without having to close my current form and open a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Controls Property to access all controls you added to a form.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx

In General I would say your application design sounds terrible. If you want to stick with WinForms I would recommend you to use Graphics instead of Controls:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287594(v=vs.71).aspx

But you will come to a point where you will have flickering. Also if double buffered. With WPF you can do such little games with about 10000 objects without flickering.

If you want to go even furthher I recommend you OpenGL or similar

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you. I want to be able to code the graphics myself, I'll look more into that. As for the artwork I have a cousin doing the animations and what not, but I wasn't sure on how to go about drawings objects like a rectangle without having to use the toolbox. I've noticed a lot of flickering using the tool box as a source, and I find it annoying dealing with a million panels on the form.

Comment: So you may mark this as answered?

Comment: I put a check mark is that how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways. If you **really** do it in with **Forms** (which is ... strange), then search and read about "DataBinding in Windows Forms". With BindingSource component and intelligent data models and some few interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanged parts of your form can automatically update when you set new data to the data models. But still, gluing up a game with Forms Controls.. feels strange. It's ok to try, good excercise, but please don't get discouraged when things get bad, remember that Windows Forms Controls simply weren't designed for that. DataBindings are fun, controls are fun, layouting is fun, but it all costs much. If not done perfectly, your result will be full of glitches and will work like .. well. Just let me just say that trying to force WindowsForms Controls to do something different than a "Form" can be really disappointing sometimes.

If you are stubborn enough to still stick to WindowsForms framework, then you'll soon need to draw all or some of your graphics yourself "by hand" i.e. through some `Graphics` class, just like when you create your own controls (*controls*, not *usercontrols* which are glued up from existing ones). It's cumbersome and tedious and needs some skill, but you can get good performance out of it.

When you hit a real wall, think about moving from Forms to WPF (easier to do a nice graphics, better performance) or just move to some **gaming engine**, i.e. XNA or whatever, really.